# Sorting a list A which containes pair values (Key,Value) based on the value of a List B that is the value of the pair in List A

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a dict A which contains values as follow :

```
dict_A ={"George Washington":{
 'lname':'Washinghton',
 'fname':'George',
 'class_id':'math',
 'teacher':'John Doe', 
 'end_year_score' : 8}
```

I convert it into a list A

```
List_A = [x for x in dict_A.iteritems()]
```

my List_A is now the following :

```
[(George Washington', {, u'fname': 'George', u'class_id' : 'math', u'teacher' : 'John Doe', u'end_year_score' : 8})]
```

**new edit**

Example of List_B

```
List_B = [(George Washington', {, u'fname': 'George', u'lname': 'Washington' u'class_id' : 'math', u'teacher' : 'John Doe', u'end_year_score' : 8}), (Genghis Khan', {u'fname': 'Genghis ', u'lname':'Khan', u'class_id' : 'math', u'teacher' : 'John Doe', u'end_year_score' : 6}), ('Queen Victoria', {u'fname': 'Queen', u'lname':'Victoria', u'class_id' : 'math', u'teacher' : 'John Doe', u'end_year_score' : 5}), etc...,]
```

But like i said i have a List_B as the Value of the pairs of my List_A.

Now let s say i want to sort my List_A based on the numerical value of **end_year_score** of my List_B. How would i do that?

i have tried this :

```
List_A.sort(key=lambda x: x[4]) >>> IndexError: tuple index out of range
List_A.sort(key=lambda x: x[1,4]) >>> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
List_A.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]['end_year_score') >>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Is it actually possible?

Comment: Sorry, what is List_B? But note that the third syntax you give is correct, and works for the data you provide.

Comment: where does `Michel PAULIN` come from ? c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tuple has a string and a dict

This is how you may do it

```
List_A.sort(cmp = lambda x,y:cmp(x[1]['end_year_score'],y[1]['end_year_score']))
```

Comment: @glaziko always ready to help,please accept the answer as correct answer